# Incomplete, skipped, or risky tests in Cakephp Unit Testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP version : 3.7.7

I have written below test case.

```
public function testDashboard()
    {
    $this->get( __('user/dashboard') );
    $branches   = $this->viewVariable('branches');
    $this->assertEquals(1, !empty($branches));
}
```

For this controller code

```
public function dashboard()
{
    $this->loadModel('Branches');
    $this->loadModel('Zones');

    $branches  = $this->Branches->find()
        ->where( ['Branches.status' => 1] )
        ->contain(['Zones'])
        ->order(['Branches.id' => 'ASC', 'Branches.name' => 'ASC'])
        ->toArray();// If I put first() then it works

    $this->set(compact('branches'));
}
```

When I run the test case I am getting below Error

> Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own output buffers
> OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
> Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Risky: 1.

I works if:

1. If I put `first()` instead `toArray()`
2. Or just set `$branches = []`

How to solve this issue ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when for example an exception is being triggered while evaluating a template, this will cause the output buffer used for capturing the template output to not be closed, resulting in that error. This has been fixed in CakePHP [3.9.2](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/14906) and [4.1.3](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/14901) respectively, so you might want to consider upgrading.

That being said, check your CakePHP debug/error logs, you should find the underlying error in there that triggers this problem. Whether you need to use `first()` or `toArray()` depends on what the code that works with that data expects.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was 100+ entries in `Branches` which causes this error, So I reduced these to < 10 and this is working fine for me.